# Does docker build run commands twice?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

In a Dockerfile I have a FROM clause that loads the base image, say something like

```
FROM mysql:5.7
```

Inside the Dockerfile for mysql it runs commands like apt-get update, but what I don't understand is why do I need to run apt-get update after the FROM statement in my own Dockerfile? I know I need to run the apt-get update because subsequent commands fail until I run apt-get, but I thought the FROM image would have already run these commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Dockerfile for mysql](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/eeb0c33dfcad3db46a0dfb24c352d2a1601c7667/5.7/Dockerfile), you'll see a pattern like the following on a few RUN commands:

```
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      ca-certificates \
      wget \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

The first line gathers the current state of the package repos, then an install is run, and finally the package repo state is removed from the filesystem. This is following the [best practices from Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#run) to prevent two issues:

1. Cleaning up unneeded files in the same run command to prevent bloat in image layers.
2. Removing cache data that will eventually become stale and cause errors should it be reused once it becomes stale.

The common error is trying to separate the `apt-get update` from the `apt-get install` with two separate RUN commands. Because of how docker caches layers, if the apt-get update command is identical to the command run long ago, docker will reuse the cached results. If you then change the `apt-get install` command to include different packages, you'll find the image will fail to build since the cached update command points to images that are no longer in the package repositories.